# In Corona SDK, how can I stop a function?

Tags: function, lua, coronasdk

Is there a way to stop a function without making it `nil`?  Like a "function.stop" kind of thing?

Comment: What is your "stop" mean?     return the function any time?

Comment: Please improve your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exit a function before it ends simply by calling the "return"s statement:

```
local function doSomething()
    if leaveEarly then
        return
    else 
        -- do other stuff
    end
    -- do more stuff
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.4.html) use `do return end`

```
function foo ()
  do return end
  ...             -- statements not reached
end
```

Comment: What I mean is, when an event occurs I want several functions to stop.   Like    "  function onCollision       Function.stop   end

Answer (score 0):

A function will not do anything unless you call it. If you are talking about an event listener such as

```
Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", win)
--win is the name of the function, which is called once every frame
```

then you can remove that event listener like this:

```
Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", win)
--now win is no longer called every frame
```

If this isn't what you mean, could you post some of your code?